# Difference between помнить and запомнить?

Tags: выбор-слова

What's the difference between помнить and запомнить?

Both are translated as "remember" in Google Translate.

[I know there's another question already on the difference between помнить and вспомнить. I understand those now.]

Many thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They differ in [aspect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_aspect_in_Slavic_languages): *помнить* is imperfective (state), *запомнить* is perfective (state transition).

*Запомнить* is better translated as "memorize".

*Я помнил / я запомнил* roughly corresponds to English "I remembered (all along) / I've memorized (changed my state from non-remembering to remembering)".

As with other perfective / imperfective pairs, same ending puts the imperfective verb in present and the perfective one in future:

> *Я помню* "I remember"
>
> *Я запомню* "I'll memorize"

It's worth noting that those pairs are not necessarily the only ones possible. *Запоминать* is also an imperfective verb which could be paired with *запомнить*, it (again, roughly) corresponds to English continuous forms:

> *Я запоминал* "I was memorizing"
>
> *Я запоминаю* "I am memorizing"

Answer (score 1):

**за-** used to make imperfective verbs perfective:

```
 помнить
     An act of remembering. I can handle the act, with no wait of results.

 запомнить
     I can handle the act that has/had been (shall be) finally completed (accomplished).
```

Most Russian verbs occur in pairs, one of the pair being an imperfective verb and the other a perfective verb. For perfective verbs a prepositional prefix  **про-, по-, раз-, за-, ...** *etc.* is added.

As opposite to the OP, there is a perfective verb formed with the same prepositional prefix **за-,** wich means the start of some action:

```
  говорить         заговорить     
  to talk       to start talking

  играть           заиграть       
  to play        to begin to play

   петь            запеть         
  to sing       to start singing
```